# Karate API Testing - Way to check that there is no null in response value

Tags: karate

I have a huge response body which somewhat looks like this, appears for one request(For example: dept = 123):

```
{
"id":"7202",
"employee_name":"sammmmmmmmm",
"employee_salary":"6777",
"employee_age":"7",
"profile_image":""
}
```

While doing validation, I need to check that none of the key field value should be null in response. As the response body contains so many key fields, i do not want to check notnull for each key.

I want to perform this validation in one go. Is there any way, by which, we can validate it in one or two lines with the minimum code?

Note: This column list is not fixed. When we change the dept id, the response changes with the different set of columns. And we have to validate it with 10-15 different dept id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`karate.forEach(k, v)`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-foreach) that will process each key-value pair.

```
* def nullFound = false
* def fun = function(k, v){ if (!k) karate.set('nullFound', true) }
* eval karate.forEach(response, fun)
* match nullFound == false
```

Comment: Should it not be { if (!v) karate.set('nullFound', true) } when there is no value for a key?

Comment: @deepakmathpal I'm really confused as to what YOU consider key and value. just try it out both ways and see, it will work :|

Comment: It is because of the string(not null object) it was not working earlier.